# Insert Spark dataframe into hbase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, rdd

I have a dataframe and I want to insert it into hbase. I follow this [documenation](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes) .

This is how my dataframe look like:

```
 --------------------
|id | name | address |
|--------------------|
|23 |marry |france   |
|--------------------|
|87 |zied  |italie   |
 --------------------
```

I create a hbase table using this code:

```
val tableName = "two"
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
if(!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
          print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
          val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
          tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("z1".getBytes()))
          admin.createTable(tableDesc)
        }else{
          print("Table already exists!!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        }
```

And now how may I insert this dataframe into hbase ?

In another example I succeed to insert into hbase using this code:

```
val myTable = new HTable(conf, tableName)
    for (i <- 0 to 1000) {
      var p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      p.add("z1".getBytes(), "name".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+(i*5)))
      p.add("z1".getBytes(), "age".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes("2017-04-20"))
      p.add("z2".getBytes(), "job".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      p.add("z2".getBytes(), "salary".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      myTable.put(p)
    }
    myTable.flushCommits()
```

But now I am stuck, how to insert each record of my dataframe into my hbase table.

Thank you for your time and attention

Comment: The problem is not clear. You are doing something else. https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes tells you to define catalog and use in sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options to save DF to HBase.

Comment: yes and mention that i'm using that documentation. i am stuck here `val data = (0 to 255).map { i =>  HBaseRecord(i, "extra")}`  how to insert foreach record of my dataframe not from 0 to 255

Answer (score 1):

An alternate is to look at rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset, to insert the data into the hbase table.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("sparkToHive").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "ip's")
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181")
    config.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "tableName")

    val newAPIJobConfiguration1 = Job.getInstance(config)
    newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "tableName")
    newAPIJobConfiguration1.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])

    val df: DataFrame  = Seq(("foo", "1", "foo1"), ("bar", "2", "bar1")).toDF("key", "value1", "value2")

    val hbasePuts= df.rdd.map((row: Row) => {
      val  put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)))
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("value1"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(1)))
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf2"), Bytes.toBytes("value2"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(2)))
      (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put)
    })

    hbasePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration())
    }
```

Ref : https://sparkkb.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/save-javardd-to-hbase-using-saveasnewapihadoopdataset-spark-api-java-coding/

Comment: if you want to save to a table shouldn't it be     config.set(TableInputFormat.OUPUT_TABLE, "tableName")

Comment: The TableOutputFormat here used is an HBase class file.
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html
Because we would like to push data to HBase table , we are setting the TableOutputFormat.
TableInputFormat would have INPUT_TABLE which could be used in case we are extracting the data out of HBase.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a full example using the spark hbase connector from Hortonworks available in [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.shc/shc-core).

This example shows

- how to check if HBase table is existing
- create HBase table if not existing
- Insert DataFrame into HBase table

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder, ConnectionFactory, TableDescriptorBuilder}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog

object Main extends App {

  case class Employee(key: String, fName: String, lName: String, mName: String,
                      addressLine: String, city: String, state: String, zipCode: String)

  // as pre-requisites the table 'employee' with column families 'person' and 'address' should exist
  val tableNameString = "default:employee"
  val colFamilyPString = "person"
  val colFamilyAString = "address"
  val tableName = TableName.valueOf(tableNameString)
  val colFamilyP = colFamilyPString.getBytes
  val colFamilyA = colFamilyAString.getBytes

  val hBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConf);
  val admin = connection.getAdmin();

  println("Check if table 'employee' exists:")
  val tableExistsCheck: Boolean = admin.tableExists(tableName)
  println(s"Table " + tableName.toString + " exists? " + tableExistsCheck)

  if(tableExistsCheck == false) {
    println("Create Table employee with column families 'person' and 'address'")
    val colFamilyBuild1 = ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(colFamilyP).build()
    val colFamilyBuild2 = ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(colFamilyA).build()
    val tableDescriptorBuild = TableDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(tableName)
      .setColumnFamily(colFamilyBuild1)
      .setColumnFamily(colFamilyBuild2)
      .build()
    admin.createTable(tableDescriptorBuild)
  }

  // define schema for the dataframe that should be loaded into HBase
  def catalog =
    s"""{
       |"table":{"namespace":"default","name":"employee"},
       |"rowkey":"key",
       |"columns":{
       |"key":{"cf":"rowkey","col":"key","type":"string"},
       |"fName":{"cf":"person","col":"firstName","type":"string"},
       |"lName":{"cf":"person","col":"lastName","type":"string"},
       |"mName":{"cf":"person","col":"middleName","type":"string"},
       |"addressLine":{"cf":"address","col":"addressLine","type":"string"},
       |"city":{"cf":"address","col":"city","type":"string"},
       |"state":{"cf":"address","col":"state","type":"string"},
       |"zipCode":{"cf":"address","col":"zipCode","type":"string"}
       |}
       |}""".stripMargin

  // define some test data
  val data = Seq(
    Employee("1","Horst","Hans","A","12main","NYC","NY","123"),
    Employee("2","Joe","Bill","B","1337ave","LA","CA","456"),
    Employee("3","Mohammed","Mohammed","C","1Apple","SanFran","CA","678")
  )

  // create SparkSession
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("HBaseConnector")
    .getOrCreate()

  // serialize data
  import spark.implicits._
  val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF

  // write dataframe into HBase
  df.write.options(
    Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "3")) // create 3 regions
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
    .save()

}
```

This worked for me while I had the relevant site-xmls ("core-site.xml", "hbase-site.xml", "hdfs-site.xml") available in my *resources*.

Answer (score 0):

using answer for code formatting purposes
Doc tells:

```
sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options(
 Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
 .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark ")
 .save()
```

where **sc.parallelize(data).toDF** is your DataFrame. Doc example turns scala collection to dataframe using **sc.parallelize(data).toDF**

You already have your DataFrame, just try to call

```
yourDataFrame.write.options(
     Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
     .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark ")
     .save()
```

And it should work. Doc is pretty clear...

**UPD**

> Given a DataFrame with specified schema, above will create an HBase
>   table with 5 regions and save the DataFrame inside. Note that if
>   HBaseTableCatalog.newTable is not specified, the table has to be
>   pre-created.

It's about data partitioning. Each HBase table can have 1...X regions. You should carefully pick number of regions. Low regions number is bad. High region numbers is also bad.

Comment: thank you for your answer; may you explain this line:  `HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"`

Comment: Updated answer, see above. 5, means create 5 regions for table in HBase

Comment: and where is the catalog defined ? `case class HBaseRecord(
   col0: String,
   col1: String,
   col2: String
)

object HBaseRecord{                                                                                                             
   def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = {
      val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""       
      HBaseRecord(s, s"String$i: $t", s"String$i: $t")
  }
}` what to do after? thank you

Comment: after adding the script `object HBaseRecord` .i got this error  `error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int, t: String)HBaseRecord in object HBaseRecord
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'for' found.`  may you explaine me this error

Comment: I have no idea, better to provide full code snippet. Error is pretty obvious. You call HBaseRecord.apply record in the wrong way.

Comment: i'm using spark shell; i got that error when i run this script : `object HBaseRecord { def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = { val s = s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}""" HBaseRecord(s, i % 2 == 0, i.toDouble, i.toFloat, i, i.toLong, i.toShort, s"String$i: $t", i.toByte) } }`

Comment: @ZiedHermi it becomes challenging. Can you update your question and put yuor script there? I I don't see the line that causes compilation error

Comment: How to convert the code below to Java Spark?
df.write.options(
    Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "3")) // create 3 regions
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
    .save()