# How to write Spark Dataframe into HBase?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I'm trying to write `Spark Dataframe` into the `HBase` and followed several other blogs and one among of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111988/insert-spark-dataframe-into-hbase) but it's not working.

However I can read the data from `HBase` successfully as `Dataframe`. Also some post has used `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark` format and others `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase`. I'm not sure which one to use. `Spark - 2.2.2`; `HBase - 1.4.7`; `Scala - 2.11.12` and `Hortonworks SHC 1.1.0-2.1-s_2.11` from [here](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/com/hortonworks/shc-core/1.1.0-2.1-s_2.11/shc-core-1.1.0-2.1-s_2.11.jar).

The code is as follows:

```
case class UserMessageRecord(
                          rowkey: String,
                          Name: String,
                          Number: String,
                          message: String,
                          lastTS: String
                        )//this has been defined outside of the object scope

val exmple = List(UserMessageRecord("86325980047644033486","enrique","123455678",msgTemplate,timeStamp))

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val userDF = exmple.toDF()

//write to HBase
userDF.write
      .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog))
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save() //exception here

//read from HBase and it's working fine
def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
      spark.sqlContext
    .read
    .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
    .load()
    }
    val df = withCatalog(catalog)
df.show()
```

Here's the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:122)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(TableOutputFormat.java:177)
>       at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$.write(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:76)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1084)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.insert(HBaseRelation.scala:218)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:61)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:469)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
>       at HbaseConnectionTest.HbaseLoadUsingSpark$.main(HbaseLoadUsingSpark.scala:85)
>       at HbaseConnectionTest.HbaseLoadUsingSpark.main(HbaseLoadUsingSpark.scala)

Comment: It says null pointer exception. I guess there are some null values in the dataframe columns that you are trying to write to HBase. Because, HBase usually does not allow to write nulls.

Comment: It's not about the nulls. When I write by looping through each row like df.rdd.map(...) it works fine. But calling it as the above way throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925942/getting-null-pointer-exception-when-running-saveasnewapihadoopdataset-in-scala-s) I made additional configuration changes to SparkSession builder and the exception is gone. However, I am not clear on the cause and the fix.

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[1]")
  .appName("HbaseSparkWrite")
  .config("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", false)
  .getOrCreate()
```